# Android secured coding checker plugin for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using [Check Style](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) with eclipse. It's really helpful for checking code style. But I need another plug-in which will help me to check code security such as :

- Check is MODE_PRIVATE when creating files.
- Don’t write sensitive data to public places.
- Don’t write sensitive data to the log cat.
- Do not declare unneeded permission in the app manifest file. etc...

I searched enough but failed to get any plug-in which can check code security. Has any plugin already exists? If exist, please suggest me.

Comment: No plugin is a substitute for a *understanding* your program and the environment in which it runs.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find anything that will match your need.
For instance

> "don't write sensitive data to public places"

only you can juge if a specific data is "sensitive".

The only thing that might be possible is

> "Do not declare unneeded permission"
>   But i have no knowledge about a plugin capable of doing so.

However in order to improve you code quality and detect bug you can use

- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) with the [android ruleset](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/rules/java/android.html)
- [Find Bug](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- or use [sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/)